# How to use variable slots in a string in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk

I am working in Google Assistant's Action SDK and in my code I want a {location} slot. I have tried this:-

```js
gapp.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
 let rawInput = input.toLowerCase();
 console.log('USER SAID ' + rawInput);
  if(rawInput == `i am in ${loc}`)
  {
   console.log("User is in " + loc);
   conv.ask("Okay so you are in" + loc);
  }
 }
```

However if i say "I am in mumbai" in the simulator it doesn't enter this 'if' statement. How can I use the "loc" variable in the user input?

Comment: What `loc` variable? It's not declared or set to a value anywhere in the code you posted. *edit* oh wait; that's simply not how string templates work. They're for *creating* strings, not pattern matching.

Comment: For simplicity I have declared 'loc' variable global.

Comment: What's `loc` declared as? .. `Mumbai` or `mumbai` ? ... note that JS is case sensitive, so `"I am in mumbai"` won't match `"I am in Mumbai"`. If that's the case, use e.g. `.toLowerCase()` on both `rawInput` and `i am in ${loc}`

Comment: @LGSon it doesn't matter because *that is not what string templates do*.  There's no "matching" at all. Matching is done by regular expressions. String templates are for building string values.

Comment: @Pointy Won't `rawInput.toLowerCase() == \`i am in ${loc}\`.toLowerCase()` match if they both say `i am in mumbai` though with different letter casing?

Comment: Yes if the value of `loc` is "mumbai", but I think the OP is under the impression that the comparison to that  template string will *set* the variable if the pattern matches. That's what the code implies but of course that is not the way things actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `String.prototype.match()` match like so:

```
let found = rawInput.match(/I am in (.*)/)
if (found) {
  let location = found[1];
  console.log("User is in " + loc);
}
```